# Using http with ngBootstrap Typeahead for Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-typeahead

I'd like to use ngBootstrap for Angular 4 Typeahead for autocomplete. The example they have for remote data retrieval is using Jsonp and not http. I've been trying to find some more info to replace Jsonp with http in that example. I'm not too familiar with Observables yet so I'm trying to learn them and get better understanding about them.

I've seen this [example](https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/) but it looks **really** simple and maybe(?) leaves out a lot... for the sake of simplicity?

Can someone point in the right direction, I'm trying to find some good examples using http with ngBootstrap Typeahead.

**Edit**

```
    {
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9,
    "max_score": 4.2456956,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "query-index",
        "_type": "autocomplete",
        "_id": "AVxqBE-3t2o4jx2g0ntb",
        "_score": 4.2456956,
        "_source": {
          "suggestions": "bruce"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "query-index",
        "_type": "autocomplete",
        "_id": "AVxqBE-3t2o4jx2g0ntc",
        "_score": 3.064434,
        "_source": {
          "suggestions": "bruce wayne"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "query-index",
        "_type": "autocomplete",
        "_id": "AVxqBE-3t2o4jx2g0ntd",
        "_score": 3.064434,
        "_source": {
          "suggestions": "bruce willis"
        }
      },
```

Edit 2

```
export class AutocompleteComponent {
  model: any;
  searching = false;
  searchFailed = false;

  constructor(private autocompleteService: Elasticsearch) {}

  //formatMatches = (query: any) => query.hits.hits._source.suggestions || '';
  //formatMatches = (query: any) => query.hits.hits || '';
  formatMatches = (query: any) => <any>response.json().hits.hits || '';
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  //search = (text$: Observable<Suggestion[]>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      //.switchMap(term =>
      //Observable.fromPromise(this.autocompleteService.search(term)
      .switchMap(term =>
      this.autocompleteService.search(term)
      .do( () => this.searchFailed = false)
      .catch( () => {
        this.searchFailed = true;
        return Observable.of([]);
      }))
      .do( () => this.searching = false);
}
```

Comment: I think I got mine to work, but I ma not sure exactly how I did it. I used the example you posted here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I know a little of how to explain it. However, I am building a modal that handles filters. Below is my httpService.**getCarriers** which takes a search string.

```
getCarriers(query: string): Observable<any> {
  return this._http.get(this._ripcord + '/carriers?search_string=' + query, this.options)
    .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json().data)
    .do(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In my modal component (filters.component.ts) file, knowing that my service returns an array of objects, I had to create a **formatter** method to handle both the input as well as the results object structures.

I figured that since the ngbdTypeahead accepts an Observable I would send the term to my httpservice and allow it to return an Observable instead of trying to subscribe to it.

```
// filters.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import { HttpService } from '../../../shared/http.service';
import { Carrier } from '../../../definitions/carrier';

@Component({
  selector: 'afn-ngbd-modal-content',
  templateUrl: './modal/filters.modal.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal/filters.modal.css']
})
export class NgbdModalContentComponent {

  filtersForm: FormGroup;
  carriers: Carrier[];

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, public httpService: HttpService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  carrier_search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(200)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .do((text) => console.log(text))
      .switchMap(term =>
        this.httpService.getCarriers(term)
      )
  ;

  formatter = (x: {attributes: {name: string}}) => x.attributes.name;

  createForm() {
    this.filtersForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'afn-filters',
  templateUrl: './filters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filters.component.css']
})
export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContentComponent);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML template for my modal:

```
// filters.modal.html
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <!--<p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>-->
  <form [formGroup]="filtersForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="center-block">Carrier:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" [ngbTypeahead]="carrier_search" [inputFormatter]="formatter" [resultFormatter]="formatter">
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>

  <p>Form value: {{ filtersForm.value | json }}</p>
  <p>Form status: {{ filtersForm.status | json }}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
</div>
```

Let me know if there are any specific questions. I sort of hacked around until I got it working.

Needless to say, even though debounceTime is awesome, I still don't want to execute a request until the user has typed a minimum of 3 characters. I get an error if I try and place that logic within the switchMap.

[image]

Comment: coming back to this now, had to take care of some things. Can you explain your formatter function a bit more. I have the same deal you do, my service returns an array of objects, Im using Elasticsearch.

Comment: formatter function expression is taking each object that it is presented with from the dynamic request and drilling down to the existing property to render. What is the issue you're having with Elasticsearch? What sort of data representation being returned?

Comment: I've added an Edit above with a ES return sample that I receive. I'm just not sure how to drill down to text value of "suggestions".

Comment: Your object is a bit complex. What does your component look like? What you can't see on mine is that my Http request creates the first step of cleaning up my Observable. In your case you may need to return **data.hits.hits**

Comment: In my example <any>response.json().data; instead I think you would have <any>response.json().hits.hits

Comment: sorry about that had to get my kid in bed. So I would put <any>response.json().hits.hits in the formatter function? I'm still trying to get my head around Observables - that's part of the problem... I don't yet fully understand them... especially working with ES on them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151610/discussion-between-andrew-lobban-and-user3125823).